# SSIS Populate Variable with Table name of OLEDB source

Tags: variables, ssis

I need to populate variable with **table name of OLEDB Source**

Hi , i need buld dynamic variable for simple SSIS package that contains an  OLE DB source 
and an OLE DB Destination.

Variable which i look for like

```
MyVAR='OLEDB SOURCE TABLENAME'
```

For future development, I have above 250 packeges so i prefer not to do this manualy in each package.

Expectation: I set Variable and it recieve table name automaticaly in each package .

Thank You in advance .

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in 2 steps:

1. Add a variable in SSIS package
2. In the OLE DB Source, change the access mode to `Table name or View name variable` and select the variable you created from the drop down list

Comment: Hadi, thanks for your reply . Maybe i wasn't clear  about my needs . I have estableshed OLE DB connection to table i need extract this  table name and put it in variable .  I familliar with vice versa   setup .

Comment: @Ilya i don't think you can do this within the SSIS package, you can do this if you parse dtsx file as xml / or using regular expression or by using c# dts wrappers libraries